# AVAssetWriter can't create m4a file on iPhone 3G

Tags: ios, aac, avassetwriter

I'm trying to use AVAssetWriter to create an m4a file. It works perfectly on any devices exclude iPhone 3G. Some says, that problem is in 3G does not support AAC encoding. Is it true? if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput]) returns NO.

```
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4A
                                                          error:&assetError];
if (assetError) {
    NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
    return;
}
AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelBitmap = 0;
channelLayout.mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0;
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [ NSData dataWithBytes: &channelLayout length:sizeof( AudioChannelLayout ) ], AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                [ NSNumber numberWithInt: 192000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,nil];

AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                           outputSettings:outputSettings];

if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput]) {
    [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
}
```

Anybody knows, how to create m4a file on a iPhone 3G?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you're saying, iPhone 3G does not support "built in" encoding of AAC ([sorry, no direct link, scroll about a page down to table 1-2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW33)) so there is no way to do it without bundling your own encoder.

The problem is that bundling an AAC encoder requires a patent license. If that's something you can deal with, you should be able to compile [faad2](http://www.audiocoding.com/faad2.html) for the iPhone and use that.